# adonis-scheduler module running several times

Tags: scheduler, adonis.js

I've installed [`adonis-scheduler`](https://github.com/nrempel/adonis-scheduler) module, and I set up the time to run everyday, following the pattern according to `node-scheduler` which it makes use of:

```
static get schedule() {
  return '* */23 * * *'
}
```

But it happens that I saw results many times today, like it wasn't set for every day. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The cron expression you have listed should run every minute. You may be looking for something like `0 */23 * * *`.

[This site](https://crontab.guru/#*_*/23_*_*_*) is helpful for writing cron expressions.